# Repeat gradle build with different dependency versions

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to do something admittedly fringe. I have defined a single web application Gradle project, and I would like to build multiple releases of this project where each release uses different versions of specific dependencies. Additionally, I would like to design this in such a way that these versions could come from some dynamic source (e.g. user input) instead of something hardcoded in a file.

For example, I want to write a Spring MVC application and build this application against a number of different org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.3.* versions. The purpose is system is to build test applications for popular web frameworks with which I can test compatibility with a tool.

I effectively want to achieve with Gradle what the following bash is doing

```
for version in 4.3.12 4.3.13 4.3.14; do
    ./gradlew war -PspringVersion=$version
done
```

And the build.gradle uses `springVersion` when defining dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile "org.springframework:spring-aop:${springVersion}",
        "org.springframework:spring-context:${springVersion}",
        "org.springframework:spring-beans:${springVersion}",
        "org.springframework:spring-context-support:${springVersion}",
        "org.springframework:spring-core:${springVersion}",
        "org.springframework:spring-expression:${springVersion}",
        "org.springframework:spring-web:${springVersion}",
        "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${springVersion}",
        "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2",
        "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0"
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What you have in your question should work as-is. One thing you may want to do is add a default value for the property in `gradle.properties` so that the build does not fail when invoked without the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have arrived at a solution which is to build subprojects dynamically in settings.gradle - example project https://github.com/gilday/how-to-gradle-project-variations

Use settings.gradle to dynamicaly generate subprojects for each of the
variations of the web application we want to build.

```
| how-to-gradle-project-variations
├── app
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── variations
```

The "app" directory contains the web application project

```
app/
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com
                └── johnathangilday
                    └── HelloWorldServlet.java
```

settings.gradle generates a subproject for each of the variations of the
servlet-api dependency with which we want to build this project

```
// define versions of javax.servlet:servlet-api for which to generate 
variations of the app
def variations = ['2.3', '2.4', '2.5']

def projects = variations.collect { "${rootProject.name}-${it}" }

// include the app subproject with the servlet definitions include('app')
// include a subproject for each variation of the servlet-api
include(*projects)
```

`/.gradlew projects` shows us the dynamic subprojects generated in the
"variations" directory

```
$ ./gradlew projects

> Task :projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'how-to-gradle-project-variations'
+--- Project ':app'
+--- Project ':how-to-gradle-project-variations-2.3'
+--- Project ':how-to-gradle-project-variations-2.4'
\--- Project ':how-to-gradle-project-variations-2.5'
```